# How to solve Google hasn’t verified this app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

My web application has been reviewed. Is the scope a sensitive range? Does it still prompt a warning when using the same screen function?

I read other questions that said just use the added range, but mine still says not verified.

```
const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';
```

Added drive.file scope

Comment: Please edit your question. Include your code.  Showing which scopes you are calling in your code. and a screen shot of the scopes in your consent screen.